# Google Maps Android SDK - addMarker() seems not work on some type of device

Tags: android, google-maps

I've a function that return to me a latitude and a longitude that is used for add a marker and it work perfectly with some device : Asus,Samsung,Motorola.

But i've notice that on some phone the markers not appear and the app is not crashing or send error, this happens with Xiaomi,Honor,OnePlus.

I've read online that somethimes request position permission resolve the problem, but i'll prefer not use this.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    googleMap.setMinZoomPreference(googleMap.getMinZoomLevel());

    UiSettings settings = googleMap.getUiSettings();
    settings.setTiltGesturesEnabled(false);

    tracking(googleMap);

    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tracking(googleMap);
        }
    }, 10*1000,10*1000);

}


private void tracking(@NonNull GoogleMap gMap){
    AndroidNetworking.get(Constant.POSITION_URL)
            .setPriority(Priority.MEDIUM)
            .build()
            .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject IssLocationResponse) {

                    try {


                        String success = IssLocationResponse.getString("message");

                        JSONObject ISSPosition = IssLocationResponse.getJSONObject("iss_position");

                        double latitude = Double.parseDouble(ISSPosition.getString("latitude"));
                        double longitude = Double.parseDouble(ISSPosition.getString("longitude"));

                        long timestamp = IssLocationResponse.getLong("timestamp");



                        gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(new LatLng(latitude,longitude))
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
                        );

                        //gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(latitude,longitude)));
                        //gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10));


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        //TODO Handle error 
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(ANError error) {
                    //Handle error
                    Log.d("ERROR","err: "+error.getErrorDetail());
                }
            });
}
```

Has anybody experienced this sort of issue?

Comment: you need to show your code first

Comment: for what purpose? how it could be a code problem if work on other device? And what section of code do you want see?

Comment: @VadimEksler add the code

Comment: so you check that you get your response on xiaomi for example and you get your latitude and longitude ?

Comment: I don't have direct access to response of Xiaomi but before Tracking there is an if that raise an alertDialog if there are connection problem or values unexpected, i'm try to setup an icon from Drawable. Maybe is just a graphic problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally!

I found out that **the problem was raised during the handshake** because my Constant.POSITION_URL got an expired SSL Certificate and **this error was raised only from Android 8.0** and my test device have 7.0

For debugging pourpose i've setup an UnsafeOkHttpClient that will accept all certificate and in production i'll set a new SSL Certificate

**EDIT**

A far better solution instead of setup an UnsafeClient is add this line

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

in the manifest inside the `<application>` tag like this:

```
<application
        ...
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```